# How can I type Genzen style deduction in LyX?

Tags: lyx, logic

As a philosophy major student, I'm learning how to use LyX. And I don't know how to type genzen style deduction on LyX.

And Is there any good reference for LyX like Peter smith's for LaTeX particularly useful to logician or philosopher?

Comment: Welcome! Peter Smith covers various options for this style of deduction. You can use the same solutions in LyX as you do in LaTeX. You just need to do the equivalent of adding the packages to your preamble. There are not going to be any LyX-specific solutions out there because LyX depends on LaTeX (and LaTeX packages) for compilation. If you find it easier, you can typeset diagrams in a regular editor using something like the `standalone` class and then include them in your document using `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package. (LyX will certainly know about that.)

Comment: There used to be a site for philosophers using LaTeX. It was more general than Smith's excellent resources for logicians. Unfortunately, it seems to have disappeared. (And it wasn't LyX specific anyway.) If you have questions specifically about LyX, ask on their forums (or here). If the question is about a package for logic or whatever, ask it here if Smith's resources don't cover it. Then you can combine the two.

Comment: You might search CTAN, too. There are a couple of new packages not yet listed on Smith's site (or weren't a few weeks ago). E.g. [ebproof](http://ctan.org/pkg/ebproof) and [prftree](http://ctan.org/pkg/prftree). Also, [proof (topic)](http://ctan.org/topic/proof).

Comment: Note that one of LyX's main developers is a philosopher: http://www.brown.edu/academics/philosophy/richard-heck  . If you have a question and it is not answered here, write to lyx-users@lists.lyx.org.